# Installing wordpress on Nginx - Nginx sending install.php

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, installation, fastcgi

I'm trying to configure Nginx to serve a wordpress install (and a rails app - but this is not the problem).

I have a strange problem : I managed to get PHP work well (a basic test.php is correctly parsed), but when I want to install wordpress, Nginx **send me** the install.php file - I can download it.

It's the only file for which Nginx do that : the other wordpress files as well-served, and do redirect to install.php much more time.

I am on a Gentoo.
I work with spawn-fcgi and here is below my nginx.conf. The concerning part is the second server (wp.domain.local) :

```
    user nginx nginx;
    worker_processes 1;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        use epoll;
    }

    http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        log_format main
            '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
            '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
            '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
            '"$gzip_ratio"';

        client_header_timeout 10m;
        client_body_timeout 10m;
        send_timeout 10m;

        connection_pool_size 256;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 2k;
        request_pool_size 4k;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain;

        output_buffers 1 32k;
        postpone_output 1460;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        keepalive_timeout 75 20;

        ignore_invalid_headers on;

        index index.html;

        upstream rails_app {
            server unix:/tmp/.sock fail_timeout=0;
        }

        server {
            server_name domain.local www.domain.local;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.local.access_log main;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.local.error_log info;

            root /path/to/rails/app/public;

            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

            location @app {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://rails_app;
            }

            # Rails error pages
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
            location = /500.html {
                root /path/to/rails/app/public;
            }
        }

        server {
            server_name wp.domain.local *.wp.domain.local;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/wp.domain.local.access_log main;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/wp.domain.local.error_log info;

            root /path/to/wordpress;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

            index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:65532;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
            }
        }

        server {
            server_name localhost www.localhost;

            access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access_log main;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error_log info;

            root /var/www/localhost/htdocs;

            index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
            location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:65532;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Even more strange : if I query install.php by curl, output is the one excepted !
    (curl -i http://wp.domain.local/wp-admin/install.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your try_files directive to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` to handle the query strings WordPress uses.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace '/wordpress' to your subdirectory.

```
#location = / {
    #try_files $uri $uri/wordpress /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    #}
    
    location /wordpress {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php;
    }
```